# Unable to find method PackageAndroidArtifact.getOutputDirectory()

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After updating a project to use gradle 6.7.1 and Android Studio 4.2.1, I'm getting the below error:

```
Unable to find method ''java.io.File com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.getOutputDirectory()''
'java.io.File com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.getOutputDirectory()'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Tried to 1) invalid cache/restart AS 2) clean rebuild project 3) delete .gradle and .build folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue which I solved changing the SDK Build Tools version to 30.0.2 according to the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility

Also I needed to update other plugins versions inside the main build.gradle file (top level).
"Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project."

I hope that this will work for you as well.